No https triggers found while deploying python code in Azure functions
By using Visual studio I deployed my python code as the deployment was successful But there is no link generated and also I cant see my deployment in my function app as in output terminal I can see
Http trigger are not found
The below code does is reads files from azure storage container and print the content in the file as output
As below is small portion of code but facing the same issue deployemnt successful and no http trigger found no link generated
Code:

import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

client_id = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID']
tenant_id = os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
client_secret = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET']
account_url = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_URL"]

# Create a credential
credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id=client_id, 
    client_secret=client_secret,
    tenant_id=tenant_id
)

def list_blob():
    container_name = 'prudhvicontainer'

    # Set client to access Azure storage container
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credentials)

    # Get the container client 
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)

    blob_names = []
    for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
        blob_names.append(blob.name)
    return blob_names

def get_multi_blob_data():
    container_name = 'prudhvicontainer'

    # Set client to access Azure storage container
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credentials)

    # Get the container client 
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)

    blob_data = {}
    for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob.name)
        data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
        blob_data[blob.name] = data.decode("utf-8")
    return blob_data

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    action = req.params.get('action')

    if not action:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            action = req_body.get('action')

    if action == 'list':
        blob_names = list_blob()
        return func.HttpResponse(str(blob_names), status_code=200)
    elif action == 'get':
        blob_data = get_multi_blob_data()
        return func.HttpResponse(str(blob_data), status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a valid action on the query string or in the request body. Valid actions are 'list' and 'get'.",
                       status_code=400
        )



The packages i used

 azure.identity 
 azure.storage.blob 
 import load_dotenv
import os
import openai
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
 import StringIO
import sqlparse


requiremnts.txt has 

annotated-types==0.7.0
anyio==4.4.0
azure-core==1.30.2
azure-functions==1.20.0
azure-identity==1.17.1
azure-storage-blob==12.20.0
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.6
cryptography==42.0.8
distro==1.9.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.7
isodate==0.6.1
msal==1.29.0
msal-extensions==1.2.0
numpy==2.0.0
openai==1.35.14
pandas==2.2.2
portalocker==2.10.1
pycparser==2.22
pydantic==2.8.2
pydantic_core==2.20.1
PyJWT==2.8.0
pyodbc==5.1.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.32.3
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.5.1
tqdm==4.66.4
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.2

# Windows-specific dependencies
pywin32==306; platform_system == "Windows"



local.settings.json 

{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_ID": " ",
    "AZURE_TENANT_ID": " ",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": " ",
    "AZURE_STORAGE_URL": ,
    "AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY": 
  }
}




host.json :
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

output :

12:39:50 PM PrudhviAPI: Syncing triggers...
12:39:55 PM PrudhviAPI: Querying triggers...
12:39:59 PM PrudhviAPI: Uploading settings...
12:39:59 PM: Ignored the following settings that were already the same:
- FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME
- AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags
- AZURE_CLIENT_ID
- AZURE_TENANT_ID
- AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
- AZURE_STORAGE_URL
- AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY
12:39:59 PM: WARNING: This operation will not delete any settings in "PrudhviAPI". You must manually delete settings if desired.
12:39:59 PM: Excluded the following settings:
- AzureWebJobsStorage
12:39:59 PM PrudhviAPI: No HTTP triggers found.
12:40:00 PM PrudhviAPI: Successfully uploaded settings.


I see you are using only few imports in your code but added many packages in requirements.txt file. Have you added them for future use or you are fine to add the package reference of the imports only?


Before the deployment, add the Environment variables in function app.



Add the correct packages in requirements.txt file.

annotated-types==0.7.0
anyio==4.4.0
azure-core==1.30.2
azure-functions==1.20.0
azure-identity==1.17.1
azure-storage-blob==12.20.0
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.6
cryptography==42.0.8
distro==1.9.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.7
isodate==0.6.1
msal==1.29.0
msal-extensions==1.2.0
numpy==2.0.0
openai==1.35.14
pandas==2.2.2
portalocker==2.10.1
pycparser==2.22
pydantic==2.8.2
pydantic-core==2.20.1
PyJWT==2.8.0
pyodbc==5.1.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.32.3
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.5.1
tqdm==4.66.4
typing-extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.2

# Windows-specific dependencies
pywin32==306; platform_system == "Windows"


I have done few modifications to your code which is give below.

import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

client_id = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID']
tenant_id = os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
client_secret = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET']
account_url = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_URL"]

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id, 
    client_secret=client_secret
)

def list_blob():
    container_name = 'sample-container'

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credentials)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)

    blob_names = []
    for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
        blob_names.append(blob.name)
    return blob_names

def get_multi_blob_data():
    container_name = 'sample-container'

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credentials)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)

    blob_data = {}
    for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob.name)
        data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
        blob_data[blob.name] = data.decode("utf-8")
    return blob_data

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="main")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    action = req.params.get('action')

    if not action:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            action = req_body.get('action')

    if action == 'list':
        blob_names = list_blob()
        return func.HttpResponse(str(blob_names), status_code=200)
    elif action == 'get':
        blob_data = get_multi_blob_data()
        return func.HttpResponse(str(blob_data), status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a valid action on the query string or in the request body. Valid actions are 'list' and 'get'.",
            status_code=400
        )


Got the endpoints post deployment.




I tried the requirements you mentioned and the code but still http triggers are not found

Add the variables at first before deployment in Environment Variables
